# C# generic class with "conditional" constraint?

Tags: c#, generics

```
class Factory<Product> where Product : new()
{
    public Factory()
        : this(() => new Product())
    {
    }

    public Factory(System.Func<Product> build)
    {
        this.build = build;
    }

    public Product Build()
    {
        return build();
    }

    private System.Func<Product> build;
}
```

In `Factory`, when `Product` has a public default constructor, I'd like for clients to not have to specify how to construct one (via the first constructor). However I'd like to allow situations where `Product` does not have a public default constructor (via the second constructor).

`Factory`'s generic constraint is required to allow the implementation of the first constructor, but it prohibits use with any class without a public default constructor.

Is there a way to allow for both?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not directly, but you could use a non-generic `Factory` factory (sic) with a generic method, put the type constraint on the type parameter for the *method*, and use that to supply the delegate to the unconstrained `Factory<T>` class.

```
static class Factory
{
    public static Factory<T> FromConstructor<T>() where T : new()
    {
        return new Factory<T>(() => new T());
    }
}

class Factory<TProduct>
{
    public Factory(Func<TProduct> build)
    {
        this.build = build;
    }

    public TProduct Build()
    {
        return build();
    }

    private Func<TProduct> build;
}
```